# Motorola 68030 minimum frequancy

Tags: microprocessor

I am working on building a computer with a Motorola 68030. The one I got my hands on is the 40Mhz version. In the electrical specifications [pdf](http://cache.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/ref_manual/MC68030EC.pdf) they list the minimum clock frequency for the 40Mhz version as 25Mhz. I would prefer to at least at the beginning run it slower so I don't have to worry about memory timing. What will actually happen if I run it too slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That device uses 'dynamic logic' for some blocks. This is logic that requires a clock signal just to remain operational.

The 25 MHz spec is probably actually a worst case, high temperature requirement. I expect that at room temperature you could operate 10x slower.

Comment: Thank you. Would the dynamic logic just be the cache? I  have it disabled at the moment.

Comment: No. Other important pieces of dynamic logic may include internal registers and latches. Correct behavior is not guaranteed below Fmin.

Comment: Running it slower than the guaranteed minimum isn't necessarily what you want to do for your first design though. For me that sounds like yet another thing to worry about. Unless you can step it through cycle by cycle as in a completely static design, I can't see how running it at for example 2.5 MHz would help you debug eventual problems.

Comment: The data sheet (hard to find; MC68040 refers to it) mentions that the 'system control' is dynamic logic.